# VoiceOver + Safari on macOS doesn't announce aria-expanded state properly

Tags: html, typescript, safari, accessibility, screen-readers

In our Angular app, we have a button that is responsible for opening a menu. There is a directive residing on it that contains the logic for toggling the menu. Menu in our case is just a list of elements expanded vertically, that gives a user a choice of options.

We want to make this button accessible and follow all the [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#:%7E:text=Web%20Content%20Accessibility%20Guidelines%20(WCAG)%202.1%20defines%20how%20to%20make,%2C%20learning%2C%20and%20neurological%20disabilities.). Therefore we applied `aria-expanded` attributes to it among others.

```
<button 
  (click)="onClick($event)" 
  (keydown)="onKeydown($event)"
  [attr.aria-label]="'Open menu'"
  [attr.aria-expanded]="isMenuOpen"
  [attr.aria-haspopup]="true">
  Open the menu
</button>
```

On Chrome the screen reader correctly announces the expanded or collapsed state. However, when we try to do the same on VoiceOver + Safari on macOS there is no such announcement.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried changing `aria-haspopup` from `true` to `menu`?

Comment: Which screen reader is showing that issue? Voice Over? on macOS or on iOS?

Comment: I updated the question @Andy. Thanks for pointing out the missing details!

Comment: Great. Would you have an answer to the first question as well?

Comment: That didn't work. @Andy